# Why we need `CreateThreadpoolIo` and `StartThreadpoolIo` for IOCP?

Tags: winapi, iocp

I'm trying to use IOCP relying on Windows API `CreateThreadpoolIo` and `StartThreadpoolIo`, but I found the thread pool is just to make the code behind the IO completed parallel. The async IO submit operations are also execute sequentially in the main thread. So why we need this? I think make the IO submit operations parallel can improve the throughput even if they are async operations, right?

The other cost is if we make them parallel, we might need to lock something to guarantee data consistency (thread safe operation).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do IOCP without using CreateThreadpool / StartThreadpoolIo, in that case you have to manage calling GetQueuedCompletionStatus yourself (whether in a self-managed thread pool or otherwise - it is even conceivable that it could be interleaved into the actions of the thread that started the I/O, but in that case why bother with IOCP?). StartThreadpoolIO is needed in order to have a thread waiting on GetQueuedCompletionStatus instead of WaitForMultipleObjects (or one of its variants). CancelThreadpoolIo decrements a counter saying how many IOCP operations are outstanding and if that counter reaches 0 the thread pool knows it can stop waiting on GetQueuedCompletionStatus.

Comment: *StartThreadpoolIO is needed in order to have a thread waiting* - of course no ! why you at all decide this ? `StartThreadpoolIO` simply do `AddRef` on `TP_IO`  object. `CancelThreadpoolIo` really `Release` but it not say  *how many IOCP operations are outstanding* - this is say when possible delete concrete `TP_IO` but not stop waiting on IOCP

Answer (score 0):

`CreateThreadpoolIo` - create object `TP_IO` and call `ZwSetInformationFile` with `FileCompletionInformation` and `FILE_COMPLETION_INFORMATION` for set `CompletionContext` in `FILE_OBJECT`. as result - if we do I/O on file, when it finished (if no synchronous error returned and we pass not zero `ApcContext` ) -  system queue packet to I/O port ( which we provide in `FILE_COMPLETION_INFORMATION` ) with `Key` (from `FILE_COMPLETION_INFORMATION` ) and `ApcContext` (form concrete I/O call. win32 api always pass pointer to `OVERLAPPED` here). the user callback address (`IoCompletionCallback` ) stored inside `TP_IO`

`StartThreadpoolIO`  increment reference count on `TP_IO` and `CancelThreadpoolIo` (and `CloseThreadpoolIo`) decrement this reference count. this need for manage life time of `TP_IO` - before we start any I/O operation - need increment reference count on `TP_IO`. when I/O finished - packet will be queued to I/O port. one of Threads from pool pop this packet. got `Key` ( `lpCompletionKey`) convert it to pointer to `TP_IO` and call user callback `IoCompletionCallback`. after callback return - system decrement reference count to `TP_IO`. if the I/O fail synchronous - will be no packet, no callback. so need direct decrement reference count to `TP_IO` - for this need call `CancelThreadpoolIo`